# Unable to print individual elements from an array

Tags: shell-script, array

I am writing a test script to see how arrays work in an UNIX script.

```
#! /bin/bash
arr=(one two three)
echo "${arr[0]}"
```

I was expecting the above will print 'one' which is the 0th position in the array

But when I ran it as `bash test.sh` the output printed as

```
(one two three)
```

I think it is considering the variable as a string. (I also tried `sh test.sh` and that didn't work either.)

When I tried adding the declare`declare -a arr` it says `not a valid identifier`

```
uname -a
Linux XXXXXXX 2.6.32-754.31.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 15 08:08:31 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Need some help here.  Thanks.

Comment: Prints `one` for me (`bash`). With `sh` would give `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

Comment: It would print `(one two three)` if your code read `arr='(one two three)'` (or with double quotes).

Comment: @roaima running the script as `bash test.sh` also tried with `sh test.sh`

Comment: How and where did you create the file (was it created directly on the UNIX system, or on Windows and copied there)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those comments.  Those comments made me to think differently.  The issue was with the EOL conversion.  The .sh file was created in windows and that got the EOL as 'CR and LF'.  I converted to UNIX style EOL which is only 'LF' using notepad++ and the issue disappeared.